# Automatically set div width

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in my container which are floated to the left, so they will all be aligned horizontally. I want the next div with content to be placed below the first line of divs. My plan is to add a fourth div to the first line and set it's width so that it would occupy the rest of the first line hence, making the next div move down in the second line.

I tried setting the fourth div(filler div)'s width to auto but it's not working.

Comment: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/6zyo926f/) -- check out this fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `clear:left` to the fourth `div`. This forces it onto a new row.

Answer (score 2):

I have change some of your css

**changed css**

```
#container {
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div {
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
#fourth {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

**[working JsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/6zyo926f/4/)**

Hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're searching for is the percentage width on elements.

```
.myDiv {
   width: 35%;
   float: left;
}

.mySecondDiv {
   width: 65%;
   float: right;
}
```

And with that you should keep in mind that any margin will of course break the alignment of percentage measured elements, since now they're using 100% of the screen width. Any margin added to horizontal axis will cause the `.mySecondDiv` to drop down.

If this is not what you're looking for, please provide us with a Fiddle of your situation.

**EDIT:**

Took a look at your Fiddle and came back with this solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/6zyo926f/2/

You should remove the width setting from `div` and instead, use it in the separate divs like in my example. Using `display: inline-block;` gives your containers the thing you're looking for.

Forget `float` for this. With three elements or less, it is very useful, but with this, it is not so great. To adjust them inside your `.container`, use `padding`.